# Is valid use toString for a table?

Tags: jsp, tostring, html-generation

im using a toString for display a table:

```
public String toString(){
    return(
            "<table>"
            +"<tr>"
            +"<th> ID </th>"
            +"<th> Nombre </th>"
            +"<th> Enero </th>"
            +"</tr>"
            +"<td>"+idcliente+"</td>"
            +"<td>"+nombre+"</td>"
            +"<td>"+enero+ "</td>"
            +"</tr>"
            +"</table>");
}
```

This method are in a java class with getters and setters, i want display in a jsp with jstl, this is correct?

Comment: I don't think this is good approach. You should not use toString() like this

Comment: @MatthewDiana Putting the HTML in the object *at all* is a bad approach.

Comment: OK @abnijeet  thank you!

Comment: This is 1990s vintage servlet stuff that should never be done.  See the answer below.

Comment: @duffymo Why did we *ever* think PHP/scriptlets were a good idea?

Comment: Live and learn, my friend....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're coupling representation (the class model) and presentation (the HTML) here, which is a bad design. Instead, use an HTML template such as Thymeleaf or JSP and pass the object to it:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Enero</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th:text="${cliente.idcliente}" />
    <td th:text="${cliente.nombre}" />
    <td th:text="${cliente.enero}" />
  </tr>
</table>
```

This way, you can easily make changes to the HTML without interfering with your data model (what if you want to use English in your interface?) and use your `toString()` for its proper purpose: printing out the object's state in a readable form for debugging.